# What are the advantages of a pass by reference iterator in a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

I just read this [answer by Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261228/convert-flat-array-to-the-multi-dimentional).

Note that the `$node` is pass by reference.

I always thought that variable created there is only ever temporary and exists only until the end of the loop (or maybe it remains set to the last iteration - I have not tested it).

So, what are the advantages of making it pass by reference?

I'm sure there is one, but I can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with being faster or more efficient.

PHP implements copy-on-write so a variable may refer to the same area of memory *until* you change its value.  Then when you change the variable, PHP decides whether or not to create a copy depending on whether you're accessing it by value or by reference.

### Access by value -- changes to a variable creates a copy:

```
$a = array("abc");

foreach ($a as $element) {
  $element = "def";
}

print_r($a);

Array
(
    [0] => abc
)
```

### Access by reference -- changes to a variable affect the original copy:

```
foreach ($a as &$element) {
  $element = "def";
}

print_r($a);

Array
(
    [0] => def
)
```

**Note that all objects in PHP 5 are accessed by reference *without* using the `&` operator.**
This is a good reason to use objects!

Be very careful using references in PHP, because they can have confusing effects.

Be sure to read this blog: [Do not use PHP references](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html) by PHP core developer Johannes Schlüter

Comment: *Be careful!* `$foo = array(1, 2, 3); foreach($foo as &$bar) { $bar++; } $bar = 99; echo $foo[2];` -- this prints "99". "$bar" is still a reference after the loop ends.  You can and will shoot yourself in the foot if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that it lets you manipulate the array directly.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $node) {
    $array[$key]['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

can be made shorter and more efficient like this:

```
foreach ($array as &$node) {
    $node['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

In this case `$node` is not a copy of the contents of the array entry, but a reference to the actual array entry; whatever you do to it, you do to the array.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I just realised I use the former a bit and can now be more efficient.