# Recursive function for adjacent list

Tags: php

I have a problem creating a recursive function to convert a list to an object  :

```
   location :
       12 : 
         label : 'city 1'
         children:
              13 :
                label:'city2'
                children :
                   14 : 
                     label : 'city3'
                   15 : 
                     label : 'city4'
                     children :
                            16 : 
                                  .....
                                 .....

              122 :
                label : 'city 100'

    ........
```

So I hope to create a recursive function to return an object with all my list above with something like that :

```
 public static function getLocation($config , $id )
 {
    $id= current($config['id'])
    $label =   $config['id']['label']
    $children = $config['id']['label']['children']
    ....
    if(!empty($children) ){

    }else{

       foreach( ){
           getLocation($config , $id );
       }
    }
    return $obj;

 }
```

Comment: creating a function,I have just an idea I don't have any solution until now...

Comment: What kind of object do you want to return? can it be an anonymous object like StdClass or have you got a class to hydrate?

Comment: no a multidimentional array...something like that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261228/convert-flat-array-to-the-multi-dimentional

Comment: your string is a yaml one, isn't it?

Comment: yes but i can get any node with $config['...']

Comment: what i need is to charge or to load all my list in one stdClass object it's the return of my function

Comment: you are true StdClass objerct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform an array into a std class, you can use [this script](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/) :

```
function arrayToObject($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return object
        return $d;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Until now I dont know how to do?

Comment: ANd then the function I gave you is recursive

Comment: I dont have problem to convert stdClass to array,I wanna create "public static function getLocation"...

Comment: your first line is : >I have a problem creating a recursive function to convert a list to an object

I answered you so....
if you want to rename your function, you can, I do not forbid you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17249/discussion-between-artragis-and-nll)