# How to make a parent-child with foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, parent

Hello i try to make something like 
my query:

result = mysql_query('SELECT subitems.ItemID, subitems.Parent, subitems.Data, items.ID FROM subitems INNER JOIN items ON items.ID = subitems.ItemID WHERE subitems.ItemID = \''. $item['ID'] .'\' GROUP BY subitems.Parent ASC, subitems.Data ASC');

Array 
  (

```
[ItemID] => 1
    (
      [Parent] => 1
          (
              [Data] => 1
              [Data] => 2
              [Data] => 3
          )
    )

[ItemID] => 1
    (
      [Parent] => 2
          (
              [Data] => 1
              [Data] => 2
              [Data] => 3
          )
    )
```

)

i try to make a foreach for see each parent of itemID and display each items by parent, but not rewrite the name of parent everytime. thx

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe nested foreach(es)

```
 foreach ($array as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $parent) {
        foreach ($parent as $data) {
            echo $data;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: here my query

$result = mysql_query('SELECT subitems.ItemID, subitems.Parent, subitems.Data, items.ID FROM subitems INNER JOIN items ON items.ID = subitems.ItemID WHERE subitems.ItemID = \''. $item['ID'] .'\' GROUP BY subitems.Parent ASC, subitems.Data ASC');

Comment: Hi, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261228/convert-flat-array-to-the-multi-dimentional)

Comment: And also [this](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)
This is a long-long explanation, but probably you will find it helpful.